# Detecting (null) in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to detect whether passing a NSString to NSLog will return `(null)`. I've tried 
`if (string == @"") {do something}"` and `if (string == @"(null)") {do something}"` but neither seem to work. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Those aren't comparisons; they're assignments. So they wouldn't work even if that were actually the right way to check for nil.

Comment: Oops, thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your "NSString" is actually a pointer to an `NSString` (i.e. an `NSString *`). A null pointer in C is simply a pointer with the value `0`; in C, 0 is `false`, so the following is simple and idiomatic:

```
NSString *str = ...;
if (str) {
    /// str is not null
}
```

(p.s.: Your comparisons with `@""` and `@"(null)"` are comparing the addresses of the NSString pointers, not the values; to compare NSStrings, look at `-isEqualToString:`.)

Comment: is there any reason to go one step further with:  if (str===NULL)?

Comment: Well, C (and thus Objective-C) doesn't have a `===` operator, but you're free to use `==` or any other boolean operator. It's just not necessary, in the same way that writing `if (some_bool == YES)` is the same as `if (some_bool)`, just with more characters.

Comment: @pxi: It is more idiomatic in Objective-C to compare objects to `nil` rather than `NULL`. They boil down to the same thing though.

Answer (score 6):

```
if (string == nil) {
   do_something;
}
```